# XML NodeList Java object showing null in Nashorn Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, nodelist, javax.xml

I'm trying to read multiple matching values of an xpath expression from an xml file in an array in Nashorn Javascript. I'm using javax.xml.xpath classes inside Nashorn to parse xml data. I'm able to read the first
matching value just fine when I pass, XPathConstants.STRING to the evaluate function.

```java
alist = xpath.evaluate(exp, input, XPathConstants.NODESET); 
System.out.println(alist.item[0].getNodeValue());
```

Its throwing this error - `javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "getNodeValue" from undefined in <eval>`

Any ideas why the list would have all null valued elements?

Comment: Are you sure the XPath expression returns anything?  If `alist.item` is an empty array, then `alist.item[0]` will be `undefined` and this would explain the error you are getting.

Comment: /triggers/trigger[@type='buildDependencyTrigger']/properties/property[@name='dependsOn']/@value

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<triggers count="1">
 <trigger id="TRIGGER_6" type="buildDependencyTrigger">
  <properties count="2">
   <property name="branchFilter" value="+:&lt;default&gt;"/>
   <property name="dependsOn" value="Project1_BuildConfig1"/>
  </properties>
 </trigger>
 <trigger id="TRIGGER_7" type="buildDependencyTrigger">
  <properties count="2">
   <property name="branchFilter" value="+:&lt;default&gt;"/>
   <property name="dependsOn" value="Project1_BuildConfig1"/>
  </properties>
 </trigger>
</triggers>

Comment: As I mentioned, when I use XPathConstants.STRING, I do get the value from the first 'trigger' node with same xpath.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the use of `item[0]` within the line

```js
System.out.println(alist.item[0].getNodeValue());
```

`alist` appears to be a [NodeList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html), and this interface contains two methods, `getLength()` and `item(int index)`.  If you want to get the first item in the list then you need to call the `item` method using `item(0)`, rather than attempting to use `item[0]` to access `item` as if it were an array:

```js
System.out.println(alist.item(0).getNodeValue());
```